# Change the color of a part of an image in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

In the below image, the bottle neck 's color is green. How do I change the color of this to make it white using Photoshop?

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Get the image into Photoshop, get an Adjustment Layer over it, adjust it that the green part will be white:**
[image: Adjustment Layer]

**Get only the part which was green to be visible for the adjustment layer:**

[image: White Adjustment fill]
**To get there, use the Quick Selection Tool to select the green part of the bottle.**
[image: quick selection tool]
[image: Selected]

**Then inverse the selection to get everything else but the green part.**
[image: Inverse]

**Now (if not selected, select the Adjustment layer) and hit** <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Backspace</kbd> **(on a Mac), and the Adjustment Layer only applies to the white area, not to the black one.**

[image: Cut out]

**Double-click on the Adjustment Layer to get to its settings. Set the controllers like in the image. Now it could look like that, with a little bit more tweaking it's even better ;)**
[image: Result]

Comment: I am totally newbie to photoshop. I added Adjustment Layer. After that I am not able to follow what you are saying. Can you please show simple detailed steps? Thanks!

Comment: I hope this helps, with tweaking i mean to get the borders of the green part in the Adjustmentlayer more soft and the white more brighter, eventually with an other Adjustment layer and the same layer mask.

Comment: Excellent. I will try out and let you know. Thanks a ton!

Comment: awesome technique!
This technique is very usefull, since i only copy the part and do HUE/SATURATION..

Answer (score 1):

Good answer by Kimchen, except you could try omitting the quick selection and inverse steps if you select the targeted adjustment tool next to the Master drop down:[image: Screenshot]
Then 'Ctrl + click + drag' over the neck (the eyedropper tool should appear) area you want to replace. The hues will change dragging left or right. Experiment with hue changes, then increase the lightness to 100% this will then reproduce the effect Kimchen described. Any other color other than white is easy to replace!

Also google the 'Color Range' option under the 'Select' menu to check if this could assist you.

Thanks.

Answer (score -2):

If anyone is still wondering, I followed this guys tutorial and it really helped me.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BDItiU-IkyE&t=8s

Comment: Hi Jake, welcome to GDSE and thanks for your answer. We're not very fond of link-only answers however. What if the author deletes the Youtube video? Then your answer is useless. Please [edit] your answer to include the most vital steps of the video in your answer.